# Task Asynchronous Pattern and error/exception/cancellation handling

Tags: c#, exception, task-parallel-library

I often have applications where the top level function works something like

```
public Result5 ProcessAll() {
    var result1 = Process1();
    var result2 = Process2();
    var result3 = Process3(result1);
    var result4 = Process4(result1, result2);
    return Process5(result1, result2, result3, result4);
}
```

Common for the Process* functions are:

- IO Bound (database, filesystem, webservice)
- Might throw exceptions which is just propagated up in the call stack
- Might return error for some non-exceptional errors which should just stop processing and return

The top level function is also running on a background thread which can be canceled.
This means that the full implementation looks like

```
public Result5 ProcessAll(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    Result1 result1 = Process1();

    if (result1 == null)
        return null;
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    Result2 result2 = Process2();

    if (result2 == null)
        return null;
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    Result3 result3 = Process3(result1);

    if (result3 == null)
        return null;
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    Result4 result4 = Process4(result1, result2);

    if (result4 == null)
        return null;
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    return Process5(result1, result2, result3, result4);
}
```

Now lets assume that I need to speed things up by running as much as possible in parallel.

Also assume that the Process* functions implement the Task Asynchronous Pattern and uses IO Completion ports or similar.

I have not been able to find any good pattern for this.
If I ignore error/exception/cancellation it would look like this.

```
public Result5 ProcessAll(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    Task<Result1> task1 = Process1Async();
    Task<Result2> task2 = Process2Async();

    Task<Result3> task3 = task1.ContinueWith(_ => Process3Async(task1.Result)).Unwrap();

    Task<Result4> task4 = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new[] { task1, task2 }, 
                                                       _ => Process4Async(task1.Result, task2.Result)).Unwrap();

    // This will trigger all exceptions captured
    Task.WaitAll(new[] { task1, task2, task3, task4 });

    return Process5(task1.Result, task2.Result, task3.Result, task4.Result);
}
```

(I know this can be optimized like running task4 synchronous and that WaitAll isn't necessary but I'm just showing a pattern here)

If I now try to handle errors and exceptions it could look like this:

```
public Result ProcessAll(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    Task<Result1> task1 = Process1Async();
    Task<Result2> task2 = Process2Async();

    // Process 3 should not run if task1 or task2 failed or returned error
    Task<Result3> task3 = task1.ContinueWith(_ => {
         if (task1.IsFaulted || task1.Result == null)
             return null;
         if (task2.IsFaulted || (task2.IsCompleted && task2.Result == null)
             return null;
         return Process3Async(task1.Result);
    }).Unwrap();

    // Process4 should not start if any of Process1,Process2 or Process3 returned error or throw exception
    Task<Result4> task4 = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new[] { task1, task2 }, _ => {
                                                       if (task1.Faulted || task1.Result == null)
                                                           return null;
                                                       if (task2.Faulted || task2.Result == null)
                                                           return null;
                                                       if (task3.Faulted || (task3.IsCompleted && task3.Result == null))
                                                           return null;
                                                       return Process4Async(task1.Result, task2.Result)).Unwrap();

    Task.WaitAll(new[] { task1, task2, task3, task4 });
    if (task1.Result == null || 
        task2.Result == null || 
        task3.Result == null || 
        task4.Result == null)
        return null;
    return Process5(task1.Result, task2.Result, task3.Result, task4.Result);
}
```

And now I need to put in cancellation checks :-)

My question now is:
**All these checks for failures, errors and cancellation in earlier tasks becomes error prone and is not very scalable.
Am I missing something important here and doing it the wrong way?**

Comment: have you tried these links - that has that field well covered, though not sure if it fully applies to what you have - http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/06/reporting-progress-from-tasks.html - and http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html - I think you should take a look if haven't already.

Comment: I'm assuming you can't use C#5, right?

Comment: @svick .Net 3.5 and 4 only. Does await simplify running things in parallel? My understanding is that await is mostly about asynchronous work (i.e. implementing the Process* methods in this case). Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

I you can only start processes 3, 4 and 5 when all earlier processes have completed you don't have parallelism with them anyway. So you don't need to use tasks for them. You only need to use tasks for the first two which makes the problem much easier. If you choose to start them as tasks these task will always wait for the predecessor, removing any parallelism that way.

Comment: But that's not the case here. Process 3 doesn't depend on 2 and processes 3 and 4 can run concurrently.

Comment: "Process 3 should not run if task1 or task2 failed or returned error". This means that you can only tell if you want to start it if both #1 and #2 have completed. Or not?

Comment: As I understand it, process 3 should not be started if process 2 already finished with an error, but it's fine to start it if process 2 is still running. At least that's what the last piece of code in the question does.

Comment: The sample code is hard-waiting for #1 and has a bug in that it *should* wait for #2 but doesn't - it has a race condition. It is checking the result of #2 without waiting for the result to be available.

Comment: Svick is correct. I'm trying to run as much as possible in parallel. At the same time I don't want to start more work If I know that earlier tasks has failed regardless if the new task depend on them or not.

Comment: Where is the race condition? I only check t.Result if the task has completed. (cancellation need special handling)

Comment: @adrianm, the task might not have completed in which case you erroneously start #3. It might later turn out to be failed, but its too late to "unstart" #3.

Comment: @usr, I see what you mean but it is intentional. #2 normally takes a long time but it may fail fast.